# Format for capitalizing quotes

Tags: style, creative-writing, grammar

Do you have to capitalize the second part of a dialogue if the second part is separated from the first. 
“Behind every great fortune,” he said as he started to zip up his jacket, “is a great crime. Do you capitalize is?

Comment: Welcome to the site, trin carl! Your question is actually better suited to http://english.stackexchange.com/ as it is about the rules of English grammar concerning quotations. Also, don't forget that last quotation mark at the end of the quote. :) I'm sure it just got cut off in copy-and-paste, but I wanted to be safe and mention it.

Comment: Actually, this question about style is fine here. Questions like this will sometimes get a more in-depth answer on English, but a more practical answer here.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question for http://english.stackexchange.com . But the answer is no. When you are continuing a quote, as long as it doesn't begin the sentence or begin the quote, you do not capitalize it.

Comment: I disagree. This is a writing question because there are no capital letters in spoken English. You have to be writing to even think of this question. Further, only writers ever write any dialog.

Comment: English SE is very much about the written word, not just spoken.

Answer (score 1):

The capitals are *yours* — they belong to your sentence, not the speaker’s sentence. So your sentence is capitalized correctly.